# AFreeChart Tabs at graph

Tags: android, charts

I am using AFreeChart to add charts at my android app.I would like at the graph screen to add a bar with tabs.Anyone has any idea how to do it?I have looked at examples of AFreeChart but nothing similar to this.

Ask me if you need further info.

Comment: [A Very Simple Example link](http://wptrafficanalyzer.in/blog/charts-graphs-in-android-applications-series/)

Comment: @Vigbyor thank you for the examples,but these are from other chart libraries.I need from AFreeChart library.Also neither example has the bar I asked.